# Perl - Find duplicate lines in file or array

Tags: perl, line-processing

I'm trying to print duplicate lines from the  filehandle, not remove them or anything else I see asked on other questions. I don't have enough experience with perl to be able to quickly do this, so I'm asking here. What's the way to do this?

Comment: A lot depends on the size of input, sizes of lines and the potential number of duplicates. If the memory requirements are low, then the solutions with a `%duplicates` hash are adequate.

Comment: They are. I'm just using the <DATA> filehandle to quickly check something. It doesn't look like there are any duplicates, so that's good.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the standard Perl shorthands:

```
my %seen;
while ( <> ) { 
    print if $seen{$_}++;
}
```

As a "one-liner":

```
perl -ne 'print if $seen{$_}++'
```

More data? This prints `<file name>:<line number>:<line>`:

```
perl -ne 'print ( $ARGV eq "-" ? "" : "$ARGV:" ), "$.:$_" if $seen{$_}++'
```

Explanation of `%seen`:

- `%seen` declares a hash. For each *unique* line in the input (which is coming from `while(<>)` in this case) `$seen{$_}` will have a scalar slot in the hash named by the the text of the line (this is what `$_` is doing in the has `{}` braces).
- Using the postfix increment operator (`x++`) we *take* the value for our expression, remembering to *increment* it after the expression. So, if we haven't "seen" the line `$seen{$_}` is undefined--but when forced into an numeric "context" like this, it's taken as 0--and *false*.
- Then it's incremented to 1.

So, when the `while` begins to run, all lines are "zero" (if it helps you can think of the lines as "not `%seen`") then, the first time we see a line, `perl` takes the undefined value - which fails the `if` - and increments the count at the scalar slot to 1. Thus, it is 1 for any future occurrences at which point it passes the `if` condition and it printed.

Now as I said above, `%seen` declares a hash, but with `strict` turned off, any variable expression can be created on the spot. So the first time perl sees `$seen{$_}` it knows that I'm looking for `%seen`, it doesn't have it, so it creates it.

An added neat thing about this is that at the end, if you care to use it, you have a count of how many times each line was repeated.

Comment: Can you explain how $seen{$_}++ works exactly? I get that it's assigning the current line's value to a hash table, but what is the ++ doing here that makes it find duplicates?

Comment: $seen{$_} refers to a value in the hash %seen, with the key $_, which is the current line. The ++ operator will increment the hash value. This means, the first time a key appears, its value will be false, and the print will not happen. The subsequent times it is seen, it will be >0, and so the print will execute, and print without args by default prints the $_ variable.

Comment: Ah, so the key for the hash is the line, but the value is the number of times it was found in the file -1.

Comment: perl nerds impress the hell out of me.  +2 if I could!

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my %duplicates;
while (<DATA>) {
    print if !defined $duplicates{$_};
    $duplicates{$_}++;
}
```

Comment: I'd do `print unless exists $duplicates{$_}`.  And +1 for `-w`, `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 3):

Prints dupes only once:

```
perl -ne "print if $seen{$_}++ == 1"
```

Comment: This is like `sort file.txt | uniq -d` (print only duplicates) in a typical Unix shell. Is there a simple equivalent of `sort file.txt | uniq -u` (print only unique lines)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Unix-like system, you can use `uniq`:

```
uniq -d foo
```

or

```
uniq -D foo
```

should do what you want. More information: [man uniq](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq).