# Remove duplicates using regex

Tags: regex, perl

**Input:**

```
OUT :abc123: : Warning: /var/tmp/prodperim/installer/abc123.fw is older than it should be (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT :abc123 : : Warning: /var/tmp/prodperim/installer/abc123.fw.schedule is older than it should be (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT abc1234: : Warning: / filesystem 100% full
OUT abc1234: : Warning: / filesystem 100% full
OUT abc1234: : Warning: /var/tmp/prodperim/installer/abc123.fw is older than it should be (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Warning: /var/tmp/prodperim/installer/abc123.fw.schedule is older than it should be (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Succeeded.
```

I want to filter only hosts which has matched "Warnings".

**Output:**

```
abc123 
abc1234
bcd111
```

I have tried the below regex it matched all.

```
([\w]+)\s+:\s+:\s+Warning
```

Is it possible to avoid duplicates using regex?

Comment: Probably better to iterate over the lines and populate a hash.

Answer (score 3):

When you hear "unique" in Perl, think "hash":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %uniq;
while (<>) {
    /:?(\S+?)[:\s]+Warning/ and $uniq{$1} = 1;
}

print "$_\n" for keys %uniq;
```

BTW, You input and regex don't lead to the output you indicated. I changed the regex, but I'm not sure your input sample is correct. Is the placement of colons really so wild?

Answer (score 1):

```
OUT\s*:?([^:]*):(?=.*?\bWarning\b)(?:(?!OUT).)*(?!.*?\1[:\s]*Warning)
```

You can try this.See demo.Grab the capture.

http://regex101.com/r/sK8oK9/12

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'if (/\bWarning\b/) { @F[1] =~ s/(\W+)//g; print "@F[1]" }' file
abc123
abc123
abc1234
abc1234
abc1234
bcd111
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern w/ `gs` option

```
OUT\s*:?([^:]+):\s*:\s*Warning(?!.*?\1\s*:\s*:\s*Warning)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/27)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a supplement/complement to @choroba's response above since he nailed it with "when you hear 'unique' think 'hash'". You should accept @choroba's answer :-)

Here I simplified the regex part of your question into a call to `grep` in order to focus on uniqueness, changed the data in your file a bit (so it could fit here) and saved it as `dups.log`:

```
# dups.log 
OUT :abc123: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT :abc123: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw.sched old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT abc1234: : Warning: / filesystem 100% full
OUT abc1234: : Warning: / filesystem 100% full
OUT abc1234: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw.sched old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw.sched old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw.sched old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Succeeded.
```

This one-liner give the output below:

```
perl -E '++$seen{$_} for grep{/Warning/} <>; print %seen' dups.log

OUT :abc123: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT abc1234: : Warning: / filesystem 100% full
OUT :abc123: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw.sched old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT bcd111: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw.sched old (not updated for 36 hours)
OUT abc1234: : Warning: /var/tmp/abc123.fw old (not updated for 36 hours)
```

This is pretty much the same output you'd get with `uniq log_with_dups.log | grep Warning`. It works because `perl` creates a hash key from each line it reads on STDIN adding a key to the hash and incrementing its value (with `++$seen{$_}`) each time it sees the key. For `perl` "same key" here means a line that is a duplicate.  Try printing `values %seen` or using `-MDDP` and `p %seen` to get a sense of what is going on.

To get your output @choroba's regex adds the capture (instead of the whole line) to the hash:

```
perl -nE '/:?(\S+?)[:\s]+Warning/ && ++$seen{$1} }{ say for keys %seen' dups.log
```

---

*but*, just as with the whole line method above, the regex will create only one copy of the key (from the match and capture) and then increment it with `++` so in the you get "unique" keys à la `uniq` in the `%seen` hash.

---

It's a neat perl trick you never forget :-)

**References:**

- The [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884401/perl-find-duplicate-lines-in-file-or-array) has some good explanations of the perl idiom for `uniq` using a hash as per @choroba.
- This is touched on in [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f) which describes the `%seen{}` hash trick.
- Perlmaven shows how to make your own ["home made" `uniq`](http://perlmaven.com/unique-values-in-an-array-in-perl) using this approach.
- ...