# Remove Duplicate Lines

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Term::ANSIColor;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)");
$ua->timeout (10);

print "scan\n";
$site="http://aubergelasolas.com\n";

$sorm = $ua->get($site);
$karza = $sorm->content;
while($karza =~m/\/wp-content\/plugins\/(.*?)\/(.*?)' type='text\/css' media='all'/g)
{ 
$id=$1;
print "[*] Plugins: $id \n";

}
```

if run scrip font this rzlt
i need to delete or hide duplication

```
perl k.pl
scan
[*] Plugins: google-language-translator
[*] Plugins: jetpack
[*] Plugins: our-team-enhanced
[*] Plugins: wc-gallery
[*] Plugins: wc-gallery
[*] Plugins: wc-gallery
[*] Plugins: wc-gallery
[*] Plugins: wc-gallery
[*] Plugins: tablepress
```

i need to remove only duplicate lines 
i need to delete or hide duplication
and thnx

Comment: Stackoverflow is no code writing service. It makes no sense to show the code which generates the problem you are trying to solve. Instead you should show what you've tried to solve the problem, i.e.to detect a duplicate line. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884401/perl-find-duplicate-lines-in-file-or-array or just search for [perl find duplicate line](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+find+duplicate+lines) for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my %seen; # Hash for counting number of occurrences
while($karza =~m/\/wp-content\/plugins\/(.*?)\/(.*?)' type='text\/css' media='all'/g)
{ 
  $id=$1;
  next if $seen{$id}++; # skip already seen ids
  print "[*] Plugins: $id \n";
}
```